# Feuille de route : signification ?

Tags: science, université

Pour un projet de recherche on m'a demandé d'écrire une feuille de route.
Je n'ai jamais entendu en parler dans ce contexte.
De quoi s'agit-il ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cela correspond au terme anglais *roadmap*.
Il s'agit d'un document présentant les principales étapes de la réalisation d'un projet. Son contenu exact varie et dépend du contexte.